# Implement Order Screen

Tags: android

This is not a pure programming question; rather it has to do with implementation details. It is required to implement an order processing screen where a customer makes an order consisting of multiple items. It is a two step operation whereby the user has to enter the name of the customer (or pick a name off of a  list) and enter the order details (detail block in db terminology) and likewise enter the items or pick them off of a list. How is this transaction best carried out on an Android device?

(Please note that I am not asking about the programming of db operations rather about what objects are needed on the layout in order to implement such a transaction.)

Answer (score 0):

About the implementation (no code), I am trying to give the most simple yet an efficient way to do this.

1. Give the user a choice (maybe buttons) to either enter name of customer or choose from a list.
2. If the option is to enter the name, some `TextViews` and `Buttons` would do the trick.
3. For choosing from a list, try a `ListView`.
4. On clicking any of the `ListView` terms, an `Activity` with `TextViews` and `Buttons` to take the order details.
5. For choosing  the items, provide a `Dialog Window` with `check boxes` beside each item names.

Hope this helps. Get back to me if you need any help with the code.

Comment: If I am to use a listview for customers' names -- is there a way to incorporate a text box functionality to limit the names? So that if the user types "a", the list narrows down to entries beginning with the letter "a" and so on...

Comment: This is also possible and can be quiet convenient. Follow the links 
1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374177/android-search-list-while-typing

2. http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-searchbox-sort-items

Moreover, your app will work more like a contacts app in an android phone where you can perform CRUD operations on data through your database, if you want to incorporate database usage in your app, that is. you can also see this example to get an idea on how to make your app work

3. http://www.cs.trincoll.edu/hfoss/wiki/Tutorial:Making_a_Contacts_Application

Comment: Thank you. One more thing, if the items to be ordered are displayed to the user in a dialog window as you describe, would there be a possibility to enter the quantity of each item ordered? Also, how would the main screen (which contains the customer name) display the ordered items after the dialog window is closed?