# Search view shows no record found after entering 3 characters not before

Tags: android, searchview

When I search something it updates recycler view accordingly and **onQueryTextChange** method I am showing layout **No items found** if it doesn't matches, it is showing **No items found** when I enter 3rd character and if first two character doesn't match then it shows **blank screen**.

I want it to show **No items found** even if first two characters doesn't match.

```
@Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            newsListAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            if (newsListAdapter.getItemCount() < 1) {
                listRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                noRecord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                listRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                noRecord.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if your are using search view check this link [Android search list while typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374177/android-search-list-while-typing),

if you use autocompletetextview you can set the throushouldvalue

Comment: throushouldvalue is not a thing. Also, linking to other posts is discouraged since links can be deleted anytime. Just copy the relevant parts here.

Comment: SearchView.SearchAutoComplete mSearchSrcTextView = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
// show results from 1 char
        mSearchSrcTextView.setThreshold(1 OR 2);

Comment: Yeah it's great that you know the code but edit your original comment.

Answer (score 0):

For AutoCompleteTextView use this:

```
AutoCompleteTextView searchAutoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) mSearchView.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("search_src_text", "id", getPackageName()));
searchAutoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
```

The threshold value defines, how much characters you need to type in, until the first proposal can be shown (listeners get called).